# What's the best color to represent authorization?

Tags: color-scheme, color-perception

I need to represent a color for authorization, 
right now I have a green like 
    #8CBE29
but does not conbine with the other colors on the table

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what context are you using this 'authorization' in?

Comment: It's like a badge to do something. In the image we can see that the user bp it's authorized to do something, and in other cases it's not, or is on progress.

Comment: Does that small icon represent 'authorized' next to 'Wed Apr 03'?

Comment: @Beejamin, it supposed to represent a link to the authorization, I should change the icon to something more representative.

Comment: Since we're discussing colour, compulsory (possibly even useful) reference if internationalization will be a concern: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_xjcwwA-nj8k/TOgNsGXI_oI/AAAAAAAAA9M/e7VTbT3F8zw/s1600/955_coloursculture.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems more of a graphic design question. That is, it seems you know you want green for authorization but need to know what *shade* of green (the graphic design bit).

You can use a green that fits into your colour palette better. Say you took the pale blue and used the same lightness and saturation but changed only the hue to a green, you'd get something like this:

[image]

It's also more harmonious and less 'full on' for the viewer who may otherwise having trouble seeing anything *but* the green.

Comment: I believe that you're right "This seems more of a graphic design question.", so this kind of questions does not belong to ux.stackexchange?

Comment: I see http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 3):

Remember that colour shouldn't be the only way you communicate status. It possibly shouldn't even be the primary way: You should include some other depiction - an icon helps, as you've shown, but perhaps something more obviously 'authorizing' might be better.

Not everyone can see in colour - particularly red vs green. Red/Green colour blindness affects 7-10% of males - and there are people with very mild colour blindness that aren't even aware they have it (and so aren't included in statistics).

So, by all means use a colour, but perhaps make it a coloured icon with a distinctive shape, rather than the flat background colour in your example. A green tick in a circle is the obvious choice.

Another good way you can indicate status is by changing the options available, based on that status. For instance, if "Authorized" is the "complete" state, you only show the buttons/links that the user is authorized to do there. What actions can the user perform once a task is authorized?